# how to disable spring security authentication on just a few methods

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

I have spring basic authentication implemented, but there are a few urls which I don't want to be authenticated. For example, http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/signUp

How to I make this unauthenticated?

```
@Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signUp", headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String signUp(@RequestParam("user_name") String login,
            @RequestParam("pass_word") String passWord, 
            @RequestParam("first_name") String firstName,
            @RequestParam("last_name") String lastName, 
            @RequestParam("network_name") String networkName,
            @RequestParam("email") String email) {
        if(!userDAO.loginExists(login)) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setLogin(login);
            user.setFirstName(firstName);
            user.setLastName(lastName);
            user.setNetworkName(networkName);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setPassword(passWord);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
            return json("success");
        }
        return json("failure");
    }
```

Comment: Please post your spring security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/signUp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <!-- your other interceptor-url elements -->
</http>
```

Add an intercept-url pattern for your signup service which is authenticated anonymously.